# Android - Animating a layout by tapping another layout

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two `RelativeLayouts` which contains one `TextView` each.

Basically the `top layout` serves as a "`button`". When `clicked`, the other `layout` will have its animation played (expanding downwards).

In this situation, to which `layout` should I add `setLayoutAnimationListener()` so that the `top` `layout` will not be able to be clicked in method `onAnimationStart()` and can be clicked in method `onAnimationEnd()`?

Here are the layouts I meant :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_orangEmailWrapper"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/stepOneTitle"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTextWrapper"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/stepOneMessage"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

The java class

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_step_one);
...

RelativeLayout dropDownTitle = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper);
        RelativeLayout dropDownMessage = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTextWrapper);
dropDownMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dropDownTitle.setOnClickListener(translateHandler);

dropDownMessage.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            //RelativeLayout touchDisabler = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper_filler);
            RelativeLayout dropDownTitle = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper);

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                //touchDisabler.setClickable(true);
                Log.d("onStart", "Start");
                dropDownTitle.setClickable(false);
                //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //touchDisabler.setClickable(false);
                Log.d("onEnd", "End");
                dropDownTitle.setClickable(true);
                //getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                //touchDisabler.setClickable(true);
            }
        });

int height;

    View.OnClickListener translateHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout dropDownMessage = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTextWrapper);
            TextView testText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownText);
            if(dropDownMessage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                MyCustomAnimation a = new MyCustomAnimation(dropDownMessage, 350, MyCustomAnimation.COLLAPSE);
                height = a.getHeight();
                testText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.stepOneMessage));
                dropDownMessage.startAnimation(a);
            }else{
                MyCustomAnimation a = new MyCustomAnimation(dropDownMessage, 350, MyCustomAnimation.EXPAND);
                a.setHeight(height);
                testText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.stepOneMessage));
                dropDownMessage.startAnimation(a);
            }
        }
    };
```

Here's the animation class which might be useful

```
public class MyCustomAnimation extends Animation {

    public final static int COLLAPSE = 1;
    public final static int EXPAND = 0;

    private View mView;
    private int mEndHeight;
    private int mType;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

    public MyCustomAnimation(View view, int duration, int type) {

        setDuration(duration);
        mView = view;
        mEndHeight = mView.getHeight();
        mLayoutParams = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams());
        mType = type;
        if(mType == EXPAND) {
            mLayoutParams.height = 0;
        } else {
            mLayoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return mView.getHeight();
    }

    public void setHeight(int height){
        mEndHeight = height;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            if(mType == EXPAND) {
                mLayoutParams.height =  (int)(mEndHeight * interpolatedTime);
            } else {
                mLayoutParams.height = (int) (mEndHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
            }
            mView.requestLayout();
        } else {
            if(mType == EXPAND) {
                mLayoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                mView.requestLayout();
            }else{
                mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Done, was working with another `Activity`, sorry

Comment: Yess, I can still click on the top `RelativeLayout` when the animation is on going.. I've set it to `setClickable(false)` when it starts..

Comment: @0X0nosugar it is recognized as layout animation event :( I can't choose any other animation event listener other than layout animation event.. I use a custom animation I got from `Stackoverflow` somewhere.. I'm going to post it

Answer (score 0):

```
final RelativeLayout dropDownTitle = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper);

dropDownMessage.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            //RelativeLayout touchDisabler = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper_filler);

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                //touchDisabler.setClickable(true);
                Log.d("onStart", "Start");
                dropDownTitle.setClickable(false);
                dropDownMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //touchDisabler.setClickable(false);
                Log.d("onEnd", "End");
                dropDownTitle.setClickable(true);


                //getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                //touchDisabler.setClickable(true);
            }
        });
```

Try to instantiate your RelativeLayout outside of your anonymous inner class (AnimationListener) - and of course declare it *final*.

Comment: It still happens.. I still couldn't make `dropDownTitle` `false` and this might be a good information, Android Monitor doesn't show the `Log.d` inside both start end..

Comment: See my updated answer - please try and put your setVisibility(View.GONE) in the onAnimationStart instead of before the AnimationListener.

Comment: The problem is I need it `GONE` before the animation start :( The information will only be slide down when user wishes to, if not, the `RelativeLayout` containing the information has to be `GONE` :(